# DataExtension - reorder the fields on existing Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

This may seem silly !. But honestly I have faced this many times during our custom implementation but still unable to find a solution.

> ### Is there a feature either on SFMC UI or using custom API, if we could re-arrange the fields which are already existing in the Data Extension.

To be more clear I just want to bring *email_address* field as the first field in my DataExtension.

[image]

---

Note:

- I am aware that we can clear the records and **delete** the fields and **re-create** fields as per our requirement; which would re-arrange the fields.
- But I want to achieve this without clearing the records.

Comment: Indeed it is not possible, check it out https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/212049/reorganizing-fields-in-data-extension#answer-316004

Comment: @Leto thanks for providing the link. It helped and confirmed that its easy to have an alternate DE with correct order, is the BEST solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there is not a way to achieve this

Upvote this idea: "[Allow to change the order of columns in Data Extensions](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000UDRfQAO)"

Comment: @ EazyE done upvoting. Thanks for providing the link to the Idea.